# Difficulties with DIV spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site that looks similar to this:

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

I can't seem to figure out how this individual has kept each sections DIV's touching each other. I have looked through every line of his CSS, to no avail. His margin is set to 0, but so is mine, yet it still has spacing.

Mine seem to be spaced. I can fix this by coloring and adjusting border sizes of my own DIV, but I don't think that would be best practice.

Using bootstrap and my own custom css:

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    }

#blocks {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-bottom: 80px;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  }

div {
display:block;


}

.coherence-principle {
background-color:#348fd4;

}


.signalling-principle {
background-color:#9DDFFF;

}

.redundancy-principle {
background-color:#5B51CC;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: Is it because of padding?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you better - you'll need to add the relevant sections of your code to your question (don't put it in the comments, the formatting is awful)

Comment: Use the web developer tools. Click F12, use the pointer to highlight the div. Check the layout. You will see exactly what is causing the gap.

Comment: no, the spacing issue was between the two DIV's, not within the div. I think I fixed the issue though. Thanks.

Comment: That's not really a fix. Without being able to look at the rest of the code, I'm guessing that whatever Bootstrap class you applied to that div has a margin that's overpowering the styling you're using here. Did you try to apply !important to that 0 margin?

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered my own question.
 I did this:

```
div {
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
}
```

The float:left is what removes spacing (margins) between the DIV's.
I had to add the 100% width to the DIV after the float or else white-spacing existed. Must be a CSS trick?

Comment: What use was is this answer to others when there was no problematic code to go with it? Oh my div isn't aligned, here try this! Magic.

Comment: I don't understand many things with your answer. 1) DIVs are block elements by default. 2) Block elements use 100% width by default. 3) How can you have both block and floating? is this a CSS trick? 4) a DIV which is floating and width:100% is effectively block?

Comment: 1. the display:block isn't necessary, but was in the code I was working on. 2. It must be a trick. If I don't specify width, it will float left and there is white space to the right. 3. The "Float" is what removes the spacing. From what I understand it is a trick